# Ways to monitor Processes in Linux without relying on snapshots?

Tags: linux, performance, command-line

I am trying to monitor some processes on the CPU of my machine with the `top` command.
Since `top` takes snapshots and displays it, it is not very precise. Even if you take a lot of examples, you never get a precise result of whats happening.

Is there a way (and a tool) to monitor utilization better? Is it somehow possible to do it counting the CPU-cycles used by the process?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: I'm also interested in tools doing this.  I was, for instance, once searching for a signal monitoring tool, i. e. something which shows which signals are sent to which process and by which source (kill(2) or other sources).  What you can do is 'strace' and `ltrace` all your processes for fork(2)ing etc., but that's far from a decent monitoring.